# Image created with dd as no partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, backup

I installed Bodhi on my Acer C720P Chromebook. Before I started an Upgrade i created a backup with

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/path/to/image
```

And of course the upgrade went wrong. I could set up the chromebook again and i now try to get access to my backup.
But I can not mount the image and fdisk tells me there is no partition

```
fdisk -l chromi.img
Disk chromi.img: 23.6 GB, 23623172096 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2872 cylinders, total 46139008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk chromi.img doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Does any one can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with where things went wrong:

You did not backup your disk (which is /dev/sda).
You only backed-up a single partition.

In ASCII graphics:

```
-------------------- whole disk sda --------------------------    
[MBR]  [partition sda1]  [possible second partition sda2] ...
```

Your dd command told the computer to only backup the partition /dev/sda1.
But now you are telling fdisk to look for the MBR, which is not in /dev/sda1 and thus was not backupped.

In short, fdisk is correct 'chromi.img doesn't contain a valid partition table'.

Now trying to fix this:

What is your goal:

- Copying the old image back over the existing partition?
- or is it reading old data from the backup?

To copy things back you could boot from something, get access to your image (wherever it is. I assume you stored it somewhere on an external HDD or on an SDcard) and reverse the dd command to restore to the situation before the backup.

`dd of=/dev/sda1 if=/path/to/image`

To mount the **filesystem** (and not the whole disk) in the image you would:

- Create  a loopback device (e.g. `losetup -d /dev/loop0`)
- And tell it to use the image (`losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/image`)
- You could then mount the loopback device just as a regular device. (e.g. mount /dev/loop0 /mnt`)

---

For future reference (and other readers with similar problems):
What you probably wanted to do is to backup the whole disk including boot record, all partitions and empty space. To do that you would use /dev/sda (without partition number). And you might want to pile that though gzip and or netcat.

Accesing filesystems in on such a whole disk backup is possible by using an offset  (e.g. losetup /dev/loop0 disk.img -o NUMBER_HERE)

Comment: hi, thanks for you answer. Primarily I want try to get access to the old data. I tried to mount the filesystem as mentioned but i get the error `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1` seems that my image is corrupt?